# Cakephp 1.3 to 2.0 conversion

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm trying to update my Cake 1.3 app to 2.0. In some of the Model methods I'm loading the Session and Email components like this:

```
App::uses('SessionComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('EmailComponent', 'Controller/Component');

$Session = new SessionComponent();
$Email = new EmailComponent();
```

However when I load those pages I get this error:

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Component::__construct() must be an instance of ComponentCollection, none given, called in /Users/username/Sites/cake2app/app/Model/User.php on line 183 and defined [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component.php, line 77]

Notice (8): Undefined variable: collection [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component.php, line 78]
```

What's the proper way to load and use Components in Cake 2.0 like we could with Cake 1.3?

Comment: Note that CakePHP 2.0 just came out. Unless there's a reason you *need* to upgrade, I'd recommend waiting. If you must though, your answer might be found in the [Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html)

Comment: This seems like it would be a common issue for those that have been testing through the Beta and RCs though. I'm pretty much just rewriting a slopped together 1.3 app in 2.0 with no definite timeline.

Answer (score 1):

The `EmailComponent` has been replaced by the `CakeEmail` class, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html for more information about how this class is used.

And instead of the `SessionComponent` you have to use the `CakeSession` class when you want to access the session in your model. You can include this class with:

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
```

It is not necessary to instantiate this class.